# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not allowed

Tags: apache, header

Why to I get this error when the URL already is in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header!?

## error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cdn.localhost/data/voucher/16_ead32751b66fd6c7856b7db0e186574df37a7d08.pdf. Origin http://secure.localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Refused to get unsafe header "Accept-Ranges"
```

## htaccess (cdn.localhost)

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://secure.localhost"
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server `dyntest.dk` or made any changes over there?

Comment: both domains are mine

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are making the XMLHTTPRequest from a different domain. You need to modify your server side script to allow cross-domain request.

Comment: thats also what I do.. see the header

Comment: In that case I cannot tell why it does not work. Maybe there are other issues which you haven't covered in the question? For a start can you check using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

Comment: I will just use `*` and keep it that way.. now it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try sending the following headers from [this post](http://saltybeagle.com/2009/09/cross-origin-resource-sharing-demo/):

```
// Specify domains from which requests are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Specify which request methods are allowed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

// Additional headers which may be sent along with the CORS request
// The X-Requested-With header allows jQuery requests to go through
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');

// Set the age to 1 day to improve speed/caching.
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

Comment: How do you know that he is using php?

Answer (score 0):

The spec for Access-Control-Allow-Origin talks about a space-separated URL syntax. Perhaps the 2nd occurrence of the header overwrites the first in the client -- try the multi-value version in a single header.

Comment: what do you mean by `multi-value`.. could you please provide an example? :)

Comment: Not sure how wrapping will look, but one line no quotes:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://secure.dyntest.dk http://secure.localhost